# Changing the data type of an entire column in a PostgreSQL DB in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, attributes

I have a DB table for my Rails 3.2.8 app as a PostgreSQL database. In this DB I have a column of type `boolean`. The column has values filled in. I want to change the values from `boolean` to all strings.

I found out that I can run a migration to change the type of the column. However, I don't want to do this as yet as I'm not sure what happens to the values when I run such a migration. So would the `boolean` value `false` get changed to "False" and a boolean `true` to "True"?

If not then what is the best way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: is this a production database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably get `'true'` and `'false'`:

```
psql> create table t (c boolean not null);
psql> insert into t (c) values (TRUE), (FALSE);
psql> alter table t alter column c type text;
psql> select * from t;
   c   
-------
 true
 false
```

I'm not sure if that's guaranteed and I can't find an authoritative reference for what a boolean to text cast does so you might want to check what these have to say in your version of PostgreSQL:

```
psql> select TRUE::text;
psql> select FALSE::text;
```

If you want to guarantee `'True'` and `'False'` then you can use [USING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) to manually specify the conversion:

> The optional `USING` clause specifies how to compute the new column value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as an assignment cast from old data type to new.

So you could say this to force the issue:

```
alter table t
alter column c type text
using case c when TRUE then 'True' when FALSE then 'False' else NULL end
```

If you let Rails do the conversion with a standard migration then you'll get the default boolean-to-text casts, if you do the type change by hand with an SQL ALTER TABLE then you can control what happens. You can do either one inside a migration:

```
def up
    change_column :t, :c, :text
end
```

versus

```
def up
    connection.execute(%q{
        alter table ...
    })
end
```

As an aside, I'd have to question the logic of abandoning boolean columns for text columns, seems a bit backwards to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with:

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, :string
```

I just just tried it on 9.1. Just back it up `pg_dump test_db > test.sql`

You can simulate the sql on a test table to see how your version of Postgresql will react, rails should generate something like

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN col TYPE varchar(128);
```